# Why $timeout doesn't work when used inside a promise resolve?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I trying to show an message to the user that will disappear after 6 seconds using angular $timeout. Unfortunately I've been unable to make it work in conjunction with angular-translate (that I use for translations).

So this code works (without $translate service):

```
this.showMessage = function(type, text) {
    message.isVisible = true;
    message.type = type;
    message.text = text;
    $timeout(this.hideMessage, 6 * 1000);
}
```

But when I make the call inside $translate service response it doesn't (I already checked that the promise is correctly resolved):

```
this.showMessage = (type, translationId) {
    $translate(translationId).then(function (text) {
        //This works just fine.
        message.isVisible = true;
        message.type = type;
        message.text = text;
        //But hideMessage never gets called.
        $timeout(this.hideMessage, 6 * 1000);
    });
}
```

Can someone help? Thank you.

Comment: instead of using this, use scope. I think may be this keyword will not able to recognise what to hide..

Comment: You're welcome. The fact that $timeout allows `undefined` as first argument (which I believe this.hideMessage equals to inside `then` callback) makes it hard to debug.

Comment: @estus That was exactly what happened :-)